# How can I create a marking an answer as accepted one system?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Explanation:** I'm trying to make an accepted-answer system and there are three cases:

- marking a new answer as accepted one *(there is no accepted answer already)*
- undo a accepted answer
- switching from one answer to another one

Here is my code:

```js
$("body").on('click', '.fa-check', function(e) {

  // send a request by ajax and if it is successful then
  
  if( this.attr('color') == '#44b449' ){ // undo
    this.css({"color":"#aaa"}); // set gry color to marked icon
  } else { // switchin or marking a new one
    $('.fa-check').css({"color":"#aaa"}); // set gray color to all icons
    this.css({"color":"#44b449"}); // set green color to marked icon
  }
 
});
```

```css
.fa-check{
  color:#aaa;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.fa-check:hover{
  color: #999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/9e9ad91d21.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>answer1</p>
<i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<hr>
<p>answer2</p>
<i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true" style="color: #44b449;"></i>
<hr>
<p>answer3</p>
<i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

But as you see my code doesn't work. How can I fix it?

**Note:** The whole of my question is about coloring.

Comment: May you please tell me what my question has earned downvote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly your code is throwing errors as you're calling jQuery methods on `this` when it refers to a DOMElement, not a jQuery object.

To fix your issues you can simplify your logic by using classes instead of applying inline CSS styling. This allows you to simply toggle the class on click of the `.fa-check` element. Try this:

```js
$("body").on('click', '.fa-check', function(e) {
  // send a request by ajax and if it is successful then
  
  $('.fa-check').not(this).removeClass('checked');
  $(this).toggleClass('checked');
});
```

```css
.fa-check {
  color: #aaa;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.fa-check.checked {
  color: #44b449;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/9e9ad91d21.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>answer1</p>
<i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<hr>
<p>answer2</p>
<i class="fa fa-check checked" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<hr>
<p>answer3</p>
<i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Comment: I'm ashamed that I ping you again. but look, my code is sightly different in reality. It is like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/dcaqkpkp/). Noted that I **should** use `.l_acceptedanswer` class on the `.on('click' ...`. Can you please tell me how can I fix it?

Comment: No problem, in that case you need to `find()` the `fa-check` element within the `.l_acceptedanswer`. Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/dcaqkpkp/1/

Answer (score 0):

Use this method

```js
function click_div(div) {

$("#main_div div .fa-check").css("color"," #aaa"); 
$("#"+div+" .fa-check").css("color"," #44b449");

}
```

```css
#div_1,#div_2,#div_3
{
width:100%;
height:100px;
}
.fa-check{
  color:#aaa;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.fa-check:hover{
  color: #999;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/9e9ad91d21.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<div id="main_div">
<div id="div1" onclick="click_div('div1')">
<p>answer1</p>
<i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>

</div>
<hr>
<div id="div2" onclick="click_div('div2')">
<p>answer2</p>
<i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true" style="color: #44b449;"></i>
</div>
<hr>
<div id="div3" onclick="click_div('div3')">
<p>answer3</p>
<i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: Your approach doesn't support **undo**.